# Cannot import schema.measurementTagValues influxdb function in nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, influxdb

I know InfluxDB2 flux language provides a convenient way to get all the tags values for a specific bucket/measurement combination, using the schema.measurementTagValues function. I was asking which npm packet I have to install in order to use the function?

Comment: you could search in here: https://npmjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

you want to install the influxdb-client-js library to make Flux queries against InfluxDB. You can do that with one of the following commands depending on your preferred package manager:

```
$ npm install --save @influxdata/influxdb-client
$ yarn add @influxdata/influxdb-client
$ pnpm add @influxdata/influxdb-client
```

See https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-js for the full set of instructions.